# Attach PDF to PDF as attachment (not as a page) via Javascript in HTML (not in Acrobat)

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I would like to generate a PDF portfolio using JS from an HTML/CSS page on a local machine. I would use a PDF template file which includes a PDF portfolio Navigator in SWF form. I have successfully accomplished this using C# and a command line program, but can not identify the proper Javascipt components to do this browser-side or pseuo-server with Node.js. Basically, I am looking for something which will allow me to append a PDF to a new or existing PDF via configuration choices and an 'assemble' action using a JS or HTML button. iTextSharp provides the required PDF interaction functionality, but I can not figure out to run this inside an HTML to allow configuration via the HTML/CSS DOM (i.e. checkboxes, text field desciptors, etc...). Does a library with this type of functionality exist?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create a PDF using JavaScript?

On a quick google search, I found what appears to be a javascript library for creating and manipulating PDFs call [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

If you want information on how to upload files with JavaScript alone, [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is an article on how to do that. It also shows you how to use the file element.

For style, I recommend using a CSS Framework is you don't know much about CSS. I personally use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for quickly prototyping things. It's quick and easy, and has good documentation. You can also use this to see how to make a form in HTML. I haven't got any good starter tutorials for HTML off the top of my list, sorry.

If you don't know much about JavaScript, when it comes to getting the options from the form, so that you can use them as configuration options, I'd suggest using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) framework. It'll help you get up and running quickly enough

Note, all of this shouldn't replace basic training in JavaScript and HTML/CSS. Frameworks make things simpler, but if you don't know how to do something without a framework, you're going to have a hard time with a lot of the more complicated things. This goes for every language

Comment: Gareth, thank you for for your help.              I am certainly new to this, but I had looked into jsPDF and this doesn't seem to have the methods needed. PDF.ps, jsPDF.js, etc... all allow for creation of and adding of pages to a PDF, however, I haven't seen a library function in Javascript (outside the Acrobat runtime environment) which allows for embedding a file within a PDF as an attachment. Even the FileReader... mentioned in the link you sent are not applicable to this.